# Creating SDK for IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to create an SDK like AdMob for Mobile has created and want my users to use my SDK such that they will just drop my files in their project and it will be embedded in its own way.

Example:
Assume you have an IPhone project ready to post to iTunes and you want to use my SDK (like AdMob). You will go to my website and will download a zip file containing all files required to be copied there in your project. Say you have Main View named "FirstView.xib", after dropping my SDK in your project, the main view will automatically be changed to something "SDKView.xib". Is it possible?

Simply an application usually have more than one views so how it is defined that particular View is main view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "main view" is set in the application's Info.plist with the key `Main nib file Base Name`

Comment: Ok great. Is there a way I can change this with the drop of my SDK? Sounds not possible but just making sure.

Comment: an info.plist file is just a text file, so you could write some sort of script that the person would have to run. It's not the same as a drop. It might be easier for you to go the other way and provide an empty XCode project that already has your hooks built in and then let the users add their code to your project.